# Cordova - Angular - <select> tag open a new view

Tags: angularjs, cordova

I have an Angular/Cordova app and I'm trying to figure out how should I handle the HTML SELECT tag. What I would like to do is to open a new window with all the options in a list, the user picks one and returns with that value.

The problem is when I do that I lose all the data I had in the first screen as I am closing it when I move to the second one.

I am using Angular's UI.ROUTER. One thing, which I am not too convinced to do, is to save all data entered into StateParams, and when I return, place it back.

What would be the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the use case.  If you need to be able to "deep link" to the view where a link loads the view with the pop-up active then using ui-router and stateparams makes the most sense.  If deep linking isn't a concern and the user must always select something then you can just use a service/factory/value/provider in order to share the data between the controllers during the lifetime of the app.